# strapi roles permission generating error issue

Tags: strapi

I am trying to set up permissions for the editor for a collection on my Heroku Strapi instance.

I have set up permissions for the editor role for a collection called Education on my local instance. The collection Education contains a repeating component called single_course. I set full CRUD rights for the collection and its repeating component and it works without any issues.

After pushing to Heroku Strapi, when I try to set the same permission for the Editor role for the collection Education and its repeating component single_course, it gives me the following error:

> Permissions have to be defined all together for a subject field or not
> at all

The editor role for this collection needs full CRUD rights.

What am I missing?

Comment: What Strapi version are you running?

Comment: I am using strapi version 3.6.8  which at the time of writing is the latest
And I created two new collections, and on them I can't even set any CRUD operations based upon the editor role.
This issue is not in localhost, there it saves the changes, but as soon as I upload it to heroku I get the issues I mentioned previously

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not :( I had to recreate my heroku project